# Getting an enum's index from an object? (Java)

Tags: java, object, enums

I have an object Card that is created using two enums, those being Suit and Rank. These enums read as such (apologies for formatting, not quite sure how to get it right):

```
public enum Suit
{
    HEARTS(),
    DIAMONDS(),
    SPADES(),
    CLUBS();
}

public enum Rank
{
    TWO(),
    THREE(),
    FOUR(),
    FIVE(),
    SIX(),
    SEVEN(),
    EIGHT(),
    NINE(),
    TEN(),
    JACK(),
    QUEEN(),
    KING(),
    ACE();
}
```

The Card constructor is as follows:

```
public Card(Suit s, Rank r) //s and r are fields in class Card
    {
        suit = s;
        rank = r;
    }
```

So let's say a Card object is made with Suit DIAMONDS and Rank NINE, which I know to be indexes 1 and 7, respectively.

A method called Hand is dealing with an ArrayList of 5 Card objects and is going to sort them by value to make them easier to arrange in a certain manner. Is it possible to obtain these indexes from the Card object for this purpose, or is there some other way to do it?

Added note, this is for an assignment, so I am under constraint of needing to use the enums and ArrayLists.

Comment: Enums have `ordinal()` which can be useful here. For example `Rank.TWO.ordinal()` is zero as it is the first element in the enum. `Rank.THREE.ordinal()` is one, etc.

Comment: You can add an index field to your enums

Comment: Do these help? [EnumTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) and [Enumerated Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/special/enum.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a member field called `index` in your `Suit` and `Rank` enums like this:

```java
public enum Suit {
    HEARTS(0),
    DIAMONDS(1),
    SPADES(2),
    CLUBS(3);

    private final int index;

    Suit(int i) {
        this.index = i;
    }

    public int getIndex() { return this.index; }
}

public enum Rank {
    TWO(2),
    THREE(3),
    FOUR(4),
    FIVE(5),
    SIX(6),
    SEVEN(7),
    EIGHT(8),
    NINE(9),
    TEN(10),
    JACK(11),
    QUEEN(12),
    KING(13),
    ACE(1);

    private final int index;

    Rank(int i) {
        this.index = i;
    }

    public int getIndex() { return this.index; }
}
```

You can then use it your `Card` class like this:

```java
public class Card {
    private final Suit suit;
    private final Rank rank;

    public Card(Suit s, Rank r) {
        this.suit = s;
        this.rank = r;
    }

    public Suit getSuit() { return this.suit; }

    public Rank getRank() { return this.rank; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card card = new Card(Suit.DIAMONDS, Rank.NINE);

        System.out.println(card.getSuit().getIndex()); // Prints 1
        System.out.println(card.getRank().getIndex()); // Prints 9
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to define values for the particular elements in the enumeration

```
public enum CardSuits {

    HEARTS(1),
    CLUBS(2),
    DIAMONDS(3),
    SPADES(4);

    public final int rank;

    private CardSuits(int rank){
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
}
```

You can then call `CardSuits.SPADES.getRank()` in order to get it's value when needed. This way the values are completely defined by you precisely and there will be no confusion if someone swaps the order.